# Iterate through nested Django REST Framework API with KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, django, knockout.js, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I am building an application and using Django & Django REST Framework for the backend and KnockoutJS to handle my lists on the front-end.  I've used Knockout before but it was with a simple JSON list, but I am having trouble figuring out how to grab the nested JSON objects from the API and display in my template.  It will print the object structure to the console, so I know I am connected, but at the same time will print the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJson' of undefined(…)`; if I can properly iterate over the objects, I believe it may also fix the Uncaught error. Thank you.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "/api/plaques/";
    var viewModel = {};
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJson(data);
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
 });
</script>


<table data-bind="foreach: items">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't properly installed and included `ko.mappings` plugin. It is not part of core [knockout.js](/questions/tagged/knockout.js).

Also please note that the method in question is named **`ko.mapping.fromJSON`** rather than `ko.mapping.fromJson`.

> https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output